# ORA-01858 error when referencing a view from SQL Server (SSIS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

We are calling an Oracle view from an SQL Server SSIS package. When we reference this view from SSIS, we are getting the below ORA-01858 error. This view has no issues being accessed within Oracle.

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

I have narrowed down to the columns where we are bringing in the data from a varchar2 flex field as shown below.  This varchar2 field is storing the date and I am converting as shown below.  Oracle has no problems with this.  We are running into this error ever since we started calling this from SQL Server.

```
to_char(to_date(substr(wdj.dff_detail,1,9)),'YYYYMM')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like the root of the problem is choosing the wrong datatype in Oracle. If you are storing a date you should use a date datatype, not a string datatype. This has nothing to do with which DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We lack some critical information: what exactly do you store into that column? I know, it is a string that represents date value, but - in which format?

Looking at code you posted, it seems that date value occupies first 9 characters of that string, so I **presume** that it is `dd-mon-yy`.

If that's so, then look at the following example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> with wdj (dff_detail) as
  2    (select '06-mar-20 20:31' from dual union all
  3     select '25-aug-19 13:30' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6                    substr(dff_detail, 1, 9)                          sbstr,
  7            to_date(substr(dff_detail, 1, 9), 'dd-mon-yy')            dsbstr,
  8    to_char(to_date(substr(dff_detail, 1, 9), 'dd-mon-yy'), 'yyyymm') ymdbstr
  9  from wdj;

SBSTR                                DSBSTR   YMDBST
------------------------------------ -------- ------
06-mar-20                            06.03.20 202003
25-aug-19                            25.08.19 201908

SQL>
```

- lines #1 - 4: sample data
- line #6: substring of the first 9 characters
- line #7: substring converted to date, using **appropriate format mask**! That's what you miss in your code
- line #8: date displayed in `yyyymm` format (through the `to_char` function)

Of course, it won't work if any value doesn't follow format I presumed (e.g. `mar-06-20`), if it contains invalid values (e.g. `68-abc-83`) etc.

Conclusion? Don't store dates as strings.

Comment: My apologies for the late response; got pulled into other critical task. Thanks @Littlefoot for your reply. Like you mentioned, I was able to resolve the error by explicitly adding the date format to the to_date function. I like the way you have listed the columns in the select, step by step!

`to_char(to_date(substr(wdj.dff_detail,1,9),**bold**'dd-mon-yy'**bold**),'YYYYMM')`

@Sean Lange - I am working with an vendor application, so I don't have control over the data types. Lot of ERP applications which provide flex field, do this - store various data in VARCHAR2 data type.

Thank again